# Trying to make each filetype have its own icon in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icons, ruby-on-rails-3.2, file-type

I am completely new to Rails and I'm trying to make each filetype that is in a directory have its own icon, i can only get it to show one please help? Here is what I have so far.

Controller:

```
class DocsController < ApplicationController
 def port
   @files = Dir.glob("public/folder/*")

   filetype = [".pdf", ".txt"]

   if filetype.include? ".pdf"
    @extension = "pdf.png"
   elsif filetype.include? ".txt"
    @extension = "text.png"
   else
    @extension = "folder.png"
   end
 end
end
```

View:

```
<% @files.each do |file| %>
<div class="filediv">
    <%= image_tag @extension, :size => "150x150" %>
    <p><%= file.gsub("public/folder/", "") %></p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This is resulting in everything having the pdf icon, can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your if filetype.include?('.pdf') always returns true. You need to cycle on files.

Comment: Thanks, how could i re-write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add helper method

```
def extension_image(file)
  ext =File.extname(file)
  if ext==".pdf"
    "pdf.png"
  elsif ext == ".txt"
   "text.png"
  else
    "folder.png"
  end
end


 <%= image_tag extension_image(file), :size => "150x150" %>
```

filetype = [".pdf", ".txt"]

remove this code.

```
if filetype.include? ".pdf"
    @extension = "pdf.png"
   elsif filetype.include? ".txt"
    @extension = "text.png"
   else
    @extension = "folder.png"
   end
end
```

Now why is always displays a pdf extension
it's simple

```
[1,2,3].include?(1)  it's always true so no further checking
```

Checkout how include works in array.

Comment: Thanks Amar, I can't vote as i have only just signed up but thank you very much, can you explain the ext =File.extname(file) part please?